# How to use startup event in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've tried both of these examples to use a startup event in a WPF app:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/working-with-app-xaml/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx

Each one creates a method in the partial App class:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, StartupEventArgs args){
  //do something
}
```

and in App.xaml, point to it:

```
Startup = "Application_Start"
```

I always get this build error:

> MyApp.App does not contain a definition for Application_Start and no
>   extension method Application_Start accepting a first arument of type
>   MyApp.App could be found.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show enough to see what namespaces you are using for the class containing the Application_Start and the namespace used in your app.xaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `StartupEventArgs` instead of `StartEventArgs` in parameter type:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
{
    //do something           
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should create your partial class with the same namespace as your main `App` class:

```
namespace WpfAppStartEvent
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

    }
}

namespace WpfAppStartEvent
{
    public partial class App 
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
        {
            //do something           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a misspelling and will throw a design time error. I've corrected it in the OP.

Comment: @4thSpace check my answer again :)

Comment: It was a namespace issue in App.xaml.