# How to set my app.xaml to point to *.cs file instead of *.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to learn WPF.  I have done mostly back-end programming, except I did some C++ UI programming in the nineties.  So far, I have created a simple maintenance application with a few screens and I can run it fine.  I can navigate around, insert records and whatnot.  However, I have to set my app.xaml startup location to MainWindow.xaml and then instantiate my actual window inside the C# code of the class linked to it.  If I delete the MainWindow.xaml file and set my StartupLocation to wndMyMainWindow.cs, I get an error saying that it can not find the file.  Is there any way around this?  It seems sort of weird to require a non C# file type in what is supposed to be a C# UI framework.

Comment: Go to `Application.xaml` and change `StartupUri` to the required one

Comment: Basically, you do not have to use `.xaml` files. You can make everything inside of a `.cs` source files.

Comment: try use `wndMyMainWindow.xaml` as location; also if you need some complex initialization on start, there is Startup event for application: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961900/how-to-use-startup-event-in-wpf-app; also wpf works with different languages (e.g. vb.net), not exclusively c#

Comment: You can do everything withou xaml files, but why? They make your life so much easier, plus expressing UI design in markup langauge is much more clear. If you build web site - you are not going to abandon html and construct the whole visual tree in javascript, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `App.xaml` remove the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`. Then add `Startup="App_OnStartup"` and create the matching method in your `App.xaml.cs` file like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // do some code stuff like initializing your ViewModel or something else


        // Instanciate the view you want to display and show it
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or he can just override `OnStartup` method.